# Submitting forms with different controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I have these two forms for submitting data to newsfeed table, one is: controller for image path, and second is for: newsfeed content. Then I want to submit these two forms in one click and submit the first form than the second form (submit form one at a time)

```
<form id="form1" ng-submit="Submit();">
</form>

<form id="form2" ng-submit="newsfeed.regNewsfeed(regData);">
</form>
```

Comment: why do you need to submit 2 forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah just use:

```
$scope.submitBothForms = function() {
  $scope.Submit().then(function() {
    newsfeed.regNewsfeed($scope.regData)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both forms are in one controller you could do something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <form id="form1" ng-submit="submitBothForms();"></form>

  <form id="form2" ng-submit="submitBothForms();"></form>
</div>
```

in your controller, since your `Submit` function should be returning a promise you can do this:

```
$scope.submitBothForms = function() {
  $scope.Submit().then(function() {
    newsfeed.regNewsfeed($scope.regData)
  })
}
```